# Finding an Idempotent Right Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital ring such that each right ideal of $R/J(R)$ is idempotent and the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ of $R$ is nil, and $I$ be a right ideal of $R$. Assume that $i\in I$ and $x\in RiR$. I search for a non-trivial idempotent right ideal $A$ of $R$ such that $ix\in A$.

Since $ix\in (iR)^2$, we may clearly choose $A=iR$ if for any $i\in I$ one has $iR=(iR)^2$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what is supposed to happen here. In $\mathbb Z$ you only ever get trivial ideals, and of course the entire ring is always a solution to your problem. Are you missing hypotheses or something?

Comment: Is $RiR$ denoting the ideal generated by $i$? Or just literally the set of $r_1ir_2$?

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry! I added the adjective "non-trivial" for the right ideal $A$. And, yes, by $RiR$ I mean the set of all $ris$, where $r,s\in R$.

Comment: but some rings have no nontrivial idempotent ideals... So I still don't feel good about the question

Comment: @rschwieb You are right! What about the additional hypotheses which I have edited into my question, to the effect that $J(R)$ is nil and $R/J(R)$ has only idempotent right ideals? Indeed, I want decompose any right ideal into an idempotent and another right ideal of $R$ (if there is any such!).